# Pandas assigning part of a dataframe using another part

Tags: python, pandas

I moved from R to python about a year ago, and I still find pandas inscrutable sometimes.  Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(dict(x = [1,2,3], y = [4,5,6], z = [7,8,9]))
a
Out[34]: 
   x  y  z
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

I want to replace this part:

```
a.loc[a.x>1, "y":]
Out[35]: 
   y  z
1  5  8
2  6  9
```

with this part:

```
a.loc[a.x<3, 'x':"y"]
Out[36]: 
   x  y
0  1  4
1  2  5
```

so I tried to just do this:

```
a.loc[a.x>1, "y":] = a.loc[a.x<3, 'x':"y"]
```

but I got this:

```
a
Out[38]: 
     x    y    z
0  1.0  4.0  7.0
1  2.0  5.0  NaN
2  3.0  NaN  NaN
```

What the heck.  I'm guessing that this has something to do with indexing?

It works when I convert the part to be converted into a numpy array:

```
a.loc[a.x>1, "y":] = np.array(a.loc[a.x<3, 'x':"y"])

a
Out[44]: 
   x  y  z
0  1  4  7
1  2  1  4
2  3  2  5
```

presumably because this throws away all of the metadata that's tripping me up.

I have two questions:

1. What's the rationale behind pandas behavior here?  It seems a bit obtuse to me, but my expectations were shaped by my background in R (and matlab before that), and it's likely that there is a good reason.
2. More concretely:  what's the pandonic way to do what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is better represented with a picture:

[image]

The red square are the ones you retrieve by `.loc` which returns a view, and the blue one is the one you assign the values to. Since `pandas` is based on `index` and the only overlapping values is 5, the rest of the values in red square is filled with `NaN`.

You can assign the values without the index by `a.loc[a.x<3, 'x':"y"].values`, or `a.loc[a.x<3, 'x':"y"].to_numpy()`.